# Implementing Signal template in C++

Tags: c++, function, types, parameters, signals

I am trying to implement a `Signal` template in C++.

Here is what I have so far:

`Main.cpp`:

```
//Developed by Trofimov Yaroslav on 02.04.18

#include <iostream>
#include "Signal.h"

void f1() {
    std::cout << "here in f1" << std::endl;
}
void f2() {
    std::cout << "F2 F2 F2" << std::endl;
}

typedef void (* VoidResultDelegate)();

int main(void) {
    Signal<VoidResultDelegate> signalVoid;
    signalVoid.addListener(f1);
    signalVoid.addListener(f1);
    signalVoid.invoke();
    signalVoid.removeListener(f2);
    signalVoid.invoke();
    return 0;
}
```

`Signal.h`:

```
//Developed by Trofimov Yaroslav on 02.04.18

#ifndef _SIGNAL_H_TROFIMOV_
#define _SIGNAL_H_TROFIMOV_
#include "LinkedList.h"

template<typename FunctionType>
class Signal {
    LinkedList<FunctionType> _delegates;

public:
    Signal<FunctionType>(void) 
        : _delegates(LinkedList<FunctionType>()) {

    }
    ~Signal<FunctionType>(void) {

    }
    void addListener(const FunctionType& delegated) {
        _delegates.add(delegated);
    }
    void removeListener(const FunctionType& delegated) {
        _delegates.remove(delegated);
    }
    void invoke() {
        _delegates.startIteration();
        while(_delegates.hasNext()) {
            _delegates.next()();
        }
    }
};

#endif
```

`LinkedList.h`:

```
//Developed by Trofimov Yaroslav on 30.03.2018

#ifndef _LINKED_LIST_H_TROFIMOV_
#define _LINKED_LIST_H_TROFIMOV_

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template<typename T>
class LinkedList {
    template<typename T>
    struct Node {
        T _data;
        Node* _next;
        Node()
            : _next(0){}
        ~Node<T>() {
            if(_next) {
                delete _next; _next = 0;
            }
        }
    };
    Node<T>* _head;
    Node<T>* _tail;
    Node<T>* _iterator;

public:
    LinkedList<T>() 
        : _head(0), _tail(0), _iterator(0) {

    };
    ~LinkedList<T>() {
        delete _head; _head = 0;
    }
    void add(const T& element) {
        if(!_head) {
            _head = new Node<T>;
            _head->_data = element;
            _tail = _head;
            return;
        }

        Node<T>* newNode = new Node<T>;
        newNode->_data = element;
        _tail->_next = newNode;
        _tail = newNode;
        return;
    }
    void remove(const T& element) {
        if(!_head) {
            return;
        }
        if(_head->_data == element) {
            _head = _head->_next;
            return;
        }

        Node<T>* previous = _head;
        Node<T>* current = _head->_next;
        while(current) {
            if(current->_data == element) {
                previous->_next = current->_next;
                return;
            }

            previous = current;
            current = current->_next;
        }
    }
    void startIteration() {
        _iterator = _head;
    }
    bool hasNext() {
        return (_iterator)?true:false;
    }
    T& next() {
        T& res = _iterator->_data;
        _iterator = _iterator->_next;
        return res;
    }
};

#endif
```

So, what I would like to add is a generic way to pass parameters. Suppose, that now instead of `typedef void (* VoidResultDelegate)();` I have `typedef void (* VoidResultDelegate)(int i);` that means I would like `int` parameter to appear somehow in the `Signal::invoke` methods parameter list and be passed here `_delegates.next()();` this way `_delegates.next()(i);` or something alike.

Is it possible at all in C++?

What I am thinking about is passing another `typename` argument to the `Signal` which would denote the type of the argument accepted by the `Signal::invoke` and passed to the elements in the linked list in the call `_delegates.next()();`. But the problem with such an approach that I can not control the number of the arguments (it will be only one argument). And no one (by no one I mean a compiler of course) enforces me to pass the correct parameter as a `typename` to the `Signal` template. In the example above I could have passed `bool` `typename` instead of `int` and no one would notice it until the error.

Here is the updated after the answer version:

`Main.cpp` :

```
//Developed by Trofimov Yaroslav on 02.04.18

#include <iostream>
#include "Signal.h"

void f1(int i) {
    std::cout << "here in f1" << std::endl;
}
void f2(int i) {
    std::cout << "F2 F2 F2" << std::endl;
}

typedef void (* VoidResultDelegate)(int i);

int main(void) {
    Signal<VoidResultDelegate, int> signalVoid;
    signalVoid.addListener(f1);
    signalVoid.addListener(f2);
    signalVoid.invoke(-1);
    signalVoid.removeListener(f1);
    signalVoid.invoke(-1);
    return 0;
}
```

`Signal.h` :

```
//Developed by Trofimov Yaroslav on 02.04.18

#ifndef _SIGNAL_H_TROFIMOV_
#define _SIGNAL_H_TROFIMOV_
#include "LinkedList.h"

template<typename FunctionType, typename... Args>
class Signal {
    LinkedList<FunctionType> _delegates;

public:
    Signal<FunctionType, parameter>(void) 
        : _delegates(LinkedList<FunctionType>()) {

    }
    ~Signal<FunctionType, parameter>(void) {

    }
    void addListener(const FunctionType& delegated) {
        _delegates.add(delegated);
    }
    void removeListener(const FunctionType& delegated) {
        _delegates.remove(delegated);
    }
    void invoke(Args&& ... args) {
        _delegates.startIteration();
        while(_delegates.hasNext()) {
            (_delegates.next())(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
    }
};

#endif
```

`LinkedList.h`:

```
//Developed by Trofimov Yaroslav on 30.03.2018

#ifndef _LINKED_LIST_H_TROFIMOV_
#define _LINKED_LIST_H_TROFIMOV_

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template<typename T>
class LinkedList {
    template<typename T>
    struct Node {
        T _data;
        Node* _next;
        Node()
            : _next(0){}
        ~Node<T>() {
            if(_next) {
                delete _next; _next = 0;
            }
        }
    };
    Node<T>* _head, _tail, _iterator;

public:
    LinkedList<T>() 
        : _head(0), _tail(0), _iterator(0) {

    };
    ~LinkedList<T>() {
        delete _head; _head = 0;
    }
    void add(const T& element) {
        if(!_head) {
            _head = new Node<T>;
            _head->_data = element;
            _tail = _head;
            return;
        }

        Node<T>* newNode = new Node<T>;
        newNode->_data = element;
        _tail->_next = newNode;
        _tail = newNode;
        return;
    }
    void remove(const T& element) {
        if(!_head) {
            return;
        }
        if(_head->_data == element) {
            _head = _head->_next;
            return;
        }

        Node<T>* previous = _head;
        Node<T>* current = _head->_next;
        while(current) {
            if(current->_data == element) {
                previous->_next = current->_next;
                return;
            }

            previous = current;
            current = current->_next;
        }
    }
    void startIteration() {
        _iterator = _head;
    }
    bool hasNext() {
        return (_iterator)?true:false;
    }
    T& next() {
        T& res = _iterator->_data;
        _iterator = _iterator->_next;
        return res;
    }
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a partial specialization for your `Signal` class to get the return type and arguments in separate template parameters.

```
// Declare the template without any definition
template<typename FunctionType>
class Signal;

// Add partial specialization
template<typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
class Signal<ReturnType(*)(Args...)> {
    // Now you have access to return type and arguments

    // Other things...

    void invoke(Args... args) {
        _delegates.startIteration();
        while(_delegates.hasNext()) {
            _delegates.next()(args...);
        }
    }
}
```

I left out [perfect forwarding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) from the `invoke` function to keep it simple. With it it would look like this.

```
void invoke(Args&&... args) {
    _delegates.startIteration();
    while(_delegates.hasNext()) {
        _delegates.next()(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
}
```

Comment: I posted an update version above. Did I do what you proposed? If so, I am getting that strange error now : `signal.h(7): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '...'` Could you help me here, please?

Comment: @ggghahaha If you see my example, you need declare the template without any definition and only 1 template parameter first, then the specialization. Notice how the specialization has `class Signal<ReturnType(*)(Args...)> ...`. But you error message is not due to that. What compiler are you using and what version?

Comment: @ggghahaha Template parameter packs are a `c++11` feature, so you need to compile with at least c++11 enabled. All current VS version should be able to do that, but I'm not sure if it's enabled by default. Might need to activate it somewhere.